# On a TeXlive 2022 installation for Linux, where do I put user-defined files?

Tags: fontspec, texmf, texmf-local

I am running `TeXLive 2022` on Manjaro Linux.

I intend to standardize the fonts invoked as `Noto Serif` and have set up a file called `NotoSerif.fontspec` in `$HOME/texmf` with the following contents:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSerif]
  {
  Path = /path-to/extra/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/google/noto/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  UprightFont = NotoSerif-Regular,
  BoldFont = NotoSerif-SemiBold,
  ItalicFont = NotoSerif-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = NotoSerif-SemiBoldItalic
  }
```

After executing `mktexlsr` and compiling a test file, different Noto Serif fonts are selected for the regular and bold families than those specified.

However, if I include the above file in the test file, the results are as expected. So, obviously, the file `NotoSerif.fontspec` is not being recognized by my TeX installation.

My question is where do I put customized, user-specific TeX configuration files such as this? It used to be `$HOME/texmf` but that does not seem to be picked up now.

My installation path is `$HOME/extra/texlive/2022` and that tree is routinely updated by `mktexlsr`.

Comment: What do you get from `kpsewhich NotoSerif.fontspec`? My first attempt would be to place the file in `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex`.

Comment: More importantly what does `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` show from the terminal? I'm on Arch, which probably uses the same packages, and it works if I put it anywhere under `$HOME/texmf/tex` (but not if I put it right in `$HOME/texmf`).

Comment: @gusbrs: I get a null response.
@frabjous: I get `$HOME/texmf`. 
I will try both suggested locations and report back. Thanks.

Comment: The file is recognized when appended to both paths: `$HOME/texmf/tex` and `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex`. Interestingly, `mktexlsr` does not seem to be necessary for file recognition, nor does it emit output  indicating recognition of either of these paths. Thanks to @gusbrs and @frabjousm as both of your answers are valid.

Comment: Yes, files in `TEXMFHOME` are searched regardless of `mktexlsr`, but the TDS structure is expected. See `texdoc kpathsea`.

Comment: For the record, and to help others in future, may I request either of you to answer this question please.